# realgcc.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, windows-10, mingw, ada

I am trying to run a command that will compile an ada program. I installed the ada compiler through MinGW on Windows 10 64 bit. the command I write exactly is

> gcc -c .\stack.adb

the MinGW bin is in my path, and I can compile C code just fine with gcc, I only get the error in the title when I try to compile ada.

Comment: I recommend you uninstall the version you installed and download the Community version of GNAT found at https://www.adacore.com/download

Comment: Maybe my marking this question as a duplicate was over-hasty. Have a look, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install gcc-ada package if you are using Cygwin, then everything will work.
As Jim Rogers said - GNAT GPS is much better options to make Ada projects and is free to use

[image]

Comment: GNAT GPS is just and IDE.  You can use it both with the MinGW and the AdaCore releases of GNAT, depending on your needs (the run-time library provided by AdaCore is pure GPL, while that provided by MinGW has a linking exception).

Comment: I know it, I used it with different tool chains.